# Libreoffice impress notes formatting removed from slideshow

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-impress

I am creating a Libreoffice Impress (powerpoint) set of slides and the one thing I can't figure out is notes formatting.  The core issue is that I can format the notes, but when I start the slideshow, all of the formatting is removed and I end up with a difficult to read text blob wherein only newlines are preserved.

Is there any way to carry over the notes formatting into the notes display mode during a slideshow?  I've searched for an answer to this and have found nothing so I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you're notes are unreadable because line spacing does not carry forward you may want to add spaces between the notes that you want separated, this should make them easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

Notes formatting is useful for printing or exporting as PDF.  During the presentation, formatting is not shown.  However the font size can be adjusted by using the zoom controls.  According to https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/8/86/IG4208-SlidesNotesHandouts.pdf:

> Notes provide a convenient way to create reminders or add extra
>   information to slides in a presentation. Notes are not displayed
>   during a slide show. However, using dual displays, you can display any
>   notes on the second display as a presentation cue. You can also print
>   the notes and use them as handouts.

If the notes are unreadable without formatting, then perhaps it would help to enter more newlines.  If you have so many notes for one slide that they become a "difficult to read text blob", then maybe you need to simplify the notes.

Also see https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Presenter_Screen.